# Error response from daemon: ........... connect: connection refused AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-efs

Stopped reason "Error response from daemon: create ecs-parser-api-dev-45-allsorter-efs-c4c8df9386aaff820100: Post http://%2Frun%2Fdocker%2Fplugins%2Famazon-ecs-volume-plugin.sock/VolumeDriver.Create: dial unix /run/docker/plugins/amazon-ecs-volume-plugin.sock: connect: connection refused"

AWS ECS EC2 based:
It was working fine. suddenly a new revision came and it didn't run the new revision but it stopped with above error

Answer (score 0):

This indicates a problem with the ECS volume plugin and not necessarily a permissions/security group issue between ECS and EFS.

Replace your instances and ensure you are running the latest ECS AMI (or ECS agent if you have a custom AMI). That should resolve the issue.